# Flag dialog radio button sometimes fails to be selected

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, flag-dialog

Sometimes, the main radio button for "it needs moderator attention" in the flagging dialog doesn't get selected even when one of the needs-mod-attention reasons is chosen.

[image: empty radio button next to "it needs diamond moderator attention]

Submitting flags when that button is unchecked fails sometimes, but not always. I don't see it often enough to have figured out the pattern, if there is one. Can the dialog be edited so that selecting a subcategory button automatically selects the parent button as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix has been checked in and will be deployed this evening.

Answer (score 3):

A way to reproduce:

- Click "it doesn't belong here"
- Click "back"
- Click "low quality"